# wp-admin is inaccessible due to some improper page redirection

Tags: wordpress, admin

One of my client's wordpress based website is having issue that it's admin panel is inaccessible. There is some page redirection issue, I can't figure out the cause. I tried to fix the issue by renaming "plugins" folder but not worked for me.

Can someone please guide me to fix this issue?

Here is sceenshot

[image: wp-admin issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually get this issue when I've done something wrong with an `.htaccess` edit and created essentially an infinite redirect loop, and since you've just moved that is possible. That is where I'd put my money based on the relatively little information you'd given. It is also possible for plugins or the theme to create about the same problem by way of [Wp_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite). You renamed the plugins folder. Try renaming the theme to force WordPress to fall back to the default theme.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, i'll try and let you know soon.

Comment: Yes I figured out that the issue was due to .htaccess rules.

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently moved the WordPress install? In that case you might need to do some updates in the database. There are entries in the `wp_options` table that tell wordpress where your install resides, and they need to be correct.

Check for `siteurl` and `home` entries manually, or change these and a couple of other hardcoded entries in a whim:

```
update wp_options set option_value = replace(option_value, 'old.com', 'new.com');
```

Comment: There is no reason to ever change the guid. It isn't used to generate links. The GUID is a 'Globally Unique Identifier" and is part of the news feed (RSS) subsystem. [Changing it is strongly discouraged.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note). That 'Globally' part is supposed to be 'global' in a "throughout all space and time" kind of way.

Comment: Agree with @s_ha_dum, GUID is used for Feeds only. And according to [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL), you should not change GUID - Quote: `It is critical that you do NOT change the contents of this field.`

Comment: You are of course both right. I will remove the guid query from my answer to avoid people using it.